# Can a application passing user id as a private key encrypted value access another application which uses CAS for SSO

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, cas

Lets say we have two applications

1. App1 using CAS for authentication
2. External application App2 some custom authentication

And a user with id 'user1'. This user once log in to App2 we want to display a link (link for App1) which allow the user to login to App1. User once clicks the link should be taken to App1.

App2 passes only the user id encrypted with a private key to App1. It will not pass password.

User ---------> External App2 -----Encrypted user id-----> CAS ===== App1

Is this possible to implement, as the request does not contain password?
Could you please guide me on the approach as this is first time I am working on CAS and SSO.

Your help is much appreciated.

We are using CAS 3.4 and Spring 3 integration.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible, In your App1 you no need to check the password , because CAS will Authenticate, and in the other App level when you click your link (APP1) you have to pass Access token and username, in your App1 you have to use CAS libraries, those libraries will check the request is coming from trusted site or not and Access token (here we are calling as service tickets and proxy granted tickets) is valid or not. one these two check are done your authentication function / method will gets execute (you have to configure like this), if user name is exist in your data base you have to create a session and you can assume it login. the functionality may vary based on the technology and requirement.

Comment: Thanks Kamal for quick response. As App2 is an external application how can it get access token? does it need to send a request to CAS server (used by App1) to get the Access Token?

Comment: Yes , your both App1 and App2 should be configure with CAS server

Comment: The user will have different passwords in App1 and External App2. If I am not wrong in order to get Access token from App2 we need to pass userid and password, which is different from App1. How to handle this situation? Please advise.

Comment: Just consider your App2 is the parent application, from there while you are trying to login show the CAS login, CAS server also will be connected to App2 database, once you enter your user name and password CAS will authenticate and it will give Auth tokens to APP2, then App2 also will gets login.

Comment: As mentioned in my initial question, App2 has its only authentication module and does not use CAS. So not sure how they can have share the same access token. Can we some how customize this process?

Comment: As per my understand customization is not possible, And if you want to access App1 from App2 by clicking a button/ link , and you are expecting App1 should login with out asking username and password right? So you have to configure App1 and App2 through CAS server.

Comment: Can I use CAS proxy granting ticket approach?  As per my understanding App2 (External) can get a proxy ticket from CAS server and when user clicks link for App1 this ticket is passed. And this create session with no further authentication.